# Set dynamic subviews positions in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to implement the below views variations:

1. [image]
2. [image]

3.
[image]

So as you see in the first image we have price or pts and popular, in the second image we have popular and not available, and the last image we have them all, and whenever an option is no there the other option will replace its position.

It is hard to update constraints for each case and what if later we have more options

Any ideas or suggestion thanks.

Comment: Just an idea: `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: sweeper, I faced an issue with height for this approach and performance issue if we need to calculate the real height after content changed and this view will be in table view cell

Comment: set second row items bottom anchor to tableview cell bottom anchor using 'lessOrEqualTo'

Answer (score 0):

First enable tableview dynamic row height. then set all the views in cell to top.Set the second row dynamic labels bottom anchor to cell bottom anchor using **lessOrEqualTo**.This configuration will adjust your cell height automatically.You don’t need to calculate it.

[image: Guide]

Comment: what I need to is if the box near the dynamic label is not there the green box will take it's place and the other box near the green will move left.